# How to enable errors in MySQL when a JOIN clause with no ON clause is given?

Tags: sql, mysql, mysql-8.0

Writing a `JOIN` statement and forgetting the corresponding `ON` clause is a common mistake and some DBMS can show errors or warnings in such cases. In MySQL 8, is it possible to report or prevent queries with missing a missing `ON` ?
For example this simple query misses the ON part.

```
SELECT * 
FROM employees JOIN departments;
```

I can't find any [sql-mode](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/sql-mode.html) for this functionality. Or is this just a Bad Idea?

Comment: Write `explain` before your query, try to execute it and check if an error is returned?

Comment: It's not an error. This is a valid way to write a CROSS JOIN.

Comment: The best way to catch this is in code review. It's not necessarily a "bad idea" because there are legitimate uses of it. But it may not be your intended logic on a case by case basis.

Comment: Not valid ANSI/ISO SQL syntax. Will give syntax error on every(?) other dbms. I.e. a compatibility mode would be a great idea!

Comment: MariaDB and SQLite accept that non-standard syntax too. DB2, Firebird, Oracle, SQL Server, TimescaleDB, YugabyteDB and Mimer SQL don't.